# acmart package, how to use?

Tags: acm, acmart

I have downloaded the ACM tex package from its [website](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). When I want to build a sample tex file in this folder, it complains that the `acmart.cls` file is not present. When I wan to run `make` command (think that the class file is going to be built), I get a make error which says `LaTeX Error: File`environ.sty' not found`.

How can I use that package?

Comment: Probably as every other, ensure that it is inside the TeX tree. Have a look at the usual installation guides for packages, they will explain this in detail.

Comment: Well, if you look at the the zip file, there is no such cls file there. Also, I ran the tex command inside the folder.

Comment: Is there a `dtx` file and/or an `ins` file? Those would probably generate the class.

Comment: Yes. both are present

Comment: Then you have to use those to extract your file. Have you run `tex acmart.ins`? That should generate the wanted file.

Comment: `File acmart.dtx ended by \endinput` and the cls file is generated. Is that all? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: `acmart.cls` is in [package `acmart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/acmart) and can be installed using the package manager of MiKTeX or TeX Live.